# How do I prevent iptables from loading on boot?

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, kernel, iptables

I don't need iptables on my computer, since I'm behind a NAT Server and a router. I, therefore, flushed all the rules I had left to disactivate the firewall. I wonder if I could probably prevent iptables from starting on boot as well. My first trial was do blacklist all modules related to it on **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**, which were all together **ip6table_filter, ip6_tables, ip6table_filter, iptable_filter, ip_tables, iptable_filter and x_tables**. But it did not worked out. 
 
 My question is how can I avoid iptables to get loaded at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that can help, for those which blacklist.conf doesn't work, you can easily disable a module this way:

Add this line to your favorite contrab user

```
@reboot sudo rmmod iptable_nat
```

Answer (score 1):

**Flushing iptables rules / accept everything**

*You may skip this step since you mentioned in your question that you have flushed all the rules.*

```
iptables -X &&
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

After flushing your iptables rules.

Run:

- `iptables-save > save-file`
- `iptables-apply save-file`

Comment: I did indeed this step already, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @TilHund - You did this step and when you restarted you had again iptables rules setup?

Comment: Yes, I did it and it appears again on any startup.

Answer (score 1):

If You are determined to get clear of iptables:

```
sudo modprobe -r ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables
```

could do the trick for you...

Of course, If You're satisfied with result it could be made permanent...

Answer (score 0):

> My first trial was do blacklist all modules related to it on /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, which were all together ip6table_filter, ip6_tables, ip6table_filter, iptable_filter, ip_tables, iptable_filter and x_tables.

Well, if you have no rules and the firewall is disabled, those modules aren't going to be loaded anyway.

> My question is how can I avoid iptables to get loaded at startup?

Strictly speaking, `iptables` is a utility for managing the firewall functionality (aka *netfilter*) built into the Linux kernel. So your question turns into **how do I remove firewall functionality from the kernel?**

The answer to that is...build your own kernel, after configuring it appropriately.

Comment: > Well, if you have no rules and the firewall is disabled, **those modules aren't going to be loaded anyway**.
If so, then I do not understand the last lines from the dmesg output:
>[   20.477633] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team <br>
>[   20.768856] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team <br>
It seems to be loaded after any boot. Otherwise you're answer to compile my own kernel may be an option.

Comment: @TilHund - you **cannot** blacklist modules built into the kernel - the only way is to force-unload them if visible, else compile the kernel without them.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not come with firewall enabled by default. However, it does come `ufw` package/service, which is the default firewall program, as far as I know it is not active by default. You could check if the service is active with `rcconf`, you need to install the package

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf dialog
```

You will need `dialog` to run `rcconf` even though it is not marked as a dependency.
More information on `ufw` here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html

There are other firewall packages, I don't know them all, but you could do a

```
apt-cache search firewall | less
```

And see if there are some that sounds you familiar, for a service or package installed. 
Other ones I've seen in some installations are:

- `firestarter`
- `fail2ban`

Comment: Yes, I have ufw installed and disabled it in the hope this would prevent ip-tables from booting, which was without avail.